# copying struct 8 bytes at at time

Tags: c, encryption, struct, arduino, memcpy

I'm working in the arduino environment. I have a struct defined as follows. The struct will ultimately be encrypted and sent wirelessly over a radio link layer. It's 32bytes long.

```
struct SENSORTYPE{
  int sensor1:8;
  int sensor2:8;
  int sensor3:8;
  int sensor4:8;
};

struct SENSOR{
  float sensor1;
  float sensor2;
  float sensor3;
  float sensor4;
};

struct HEADER{
  byte type;
  short id;
  short to;
  short from;
  byte version;
  long _buff;
  SENSORTYPE sensortype;
  SENSOR sensor;
};

HEADER header;
```

I have an XTEA encryption/decryption routine that's defined as follows and is verified to work. It operates on two 32bit blocks at at time.

```
void xteaEncrypt( unsigned long v[2])
void xteaDecrypt(unsigned long v[2])
```

What I'm trying to do is run `header` through xteaEncrypt. I'm getting tripped up on converting my struct to the two 32bit numbers. The following is what I have so far.

```
#define BLOCK_SIZE 8
header.type = 1;                      //test value
header._buff = 1;                     //test value
byte data[BLOCK_SIZE];                //8 byte buffer to encrypt/decrypt
byte buff[32];                        //32 byte buffer to put encrypted/decrypted data into

for (uint32_t i = 0; i < 4; i++){     //4 times (4 * 8 = 32)
   memcpy(data, &header+(i*BLOCK_SIZE), BLOCK_SIZE);     //copy 8 bytes from header struct into data
   xteaEncrypt((uint32_t*)data);         //encrypt data
   memcpy(&buff+(i*8), data, BLOCK_SIZE); //put encrypted data into the new buffer
}
memcpy(&header, &buff, sizeof(header));  //copy into original header for convenience

//now decrypt it back
for (uint32_t i = 0; i < 4; i++){
   memcpy(data, &header+(i*BLOCK_SIZE), BLOCK_SIZE);
   xteaDecrypt((uint32_t*)data);
   memcpy(&buff+(i*8), data, BLOCK_SIZE);
}
memcpy(&header, &buff, sizeof(header));
```

After encryption header.type = 0xee and header._buff = C0010000. After decryption, header.type = 1 and _buff still = C0010000 so it would seem there is an error in my memcpy'ing but I can't find it. Any help would be greatly appreciated. This one has been particularly hard to debug for me. If I'm going about this completely wrong let me know and point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting tripped up by pointer arithmetic.  Consider the snippet `&header+(i*BLOCK_SIZE)`.  What you evidently expect to happen is that you'll get some address, let's call it `addr`, and then add some small number to it to calculate a new address, i.e.

```
finalAddress = addr + (i * 8);
```

But because `&header` is a pointer to a `struct HEADER`, the actual calculation the compiler does is

```
finalAddress = addr + (sizeof(struct HEADER) * i * 8);
```

The result is an address that's well beyond the end of the header for any `i` greater than 0.  The same thing is happening with `&buff+(i*8)`, since `&buff` is a pointer to 32 bytes.

To solve the problem, I recommend using intermediate variables that are `char *`, e.g.

```
char *headAddress = (char *)&header;
char *buffAddress = (char *)&buff;
for (uint32_t i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    memcpy(data, headAddress+(i*BLOCK_SIZE), BLOCK_SIZE);
    xteaEncrypt((uint32_t*)data);
    memcpy(&buffAddress+(i*BLOCK_SIZE), data, BLOCK_SIZE);
}
```

Comment: That was the problem. Just had to add `&data` rather than `data` and it worked as expected. Thanks.